# Converting a .mts HD video file to more useable/flexible format?

Tags: windows, video-conversion, mts

I had a friend ask me this and I was not sure what to recommend.  A large 19 min. HD video was shot with a Panasonic HDC-SD9P in 1920x1080. They want to send this video to friends and obviously the file off the camera is way too large.  It uses `.mts`, what seems to be a proprietary format.

I have not dealt with this format before, so I am a little sketchy on details of it. Is there some simple conversion method for Windows that I could recommend to this person to get the video in a distributable format like mp4 or similar and reduce the resolution to get the file size down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my machine [VLC media player](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) has no problem reading MTS files, and you can use it to transcode the file.

Also see this interesting article : [Best way to Convert AVCHD (.MTS) >> H.264 SD (MP4)](http://forum.videohelp.com/topic333703.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think the [**XviD4PSP**](http://www.winnydows.com/) would be a good tool for your need.

> Easy use and high quality program for converting videos for PSP, PS3, Xbox 360, iPod, iPhone, BlackBerry, Hardware DVD and PC.

[image]

Tips.

- The XviD4PSP needs Microsoft .NET framework
- the `.mts` file format is [described here](http://filext.com/file-extension/MTS)
- sometimes it helps tools if you rename the `.mts` file to `.m2ts`

Site notes on minimal system requirements.

> Windows Vista, XP SP2, Server 2003.
>   **Microsoft Framework 3.0**
>   Best and most simple way - install latest Klite Codec Pack and forgot about it.
>   Also in this case you get fast decoding function for almost any input media file format.

Answer (score 1):

You will find a lot of proposals for reading and converting AVCHD format files on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVCHD).
I read those coming from my Panasonic DMC-TZ7 with mpc hc, and I combine them with tsMuxeR (just combine, no fancy effects, but it is lightning fast).

Answer (score 0):

there is an free and automated batch [conversion pack](http://forum.videohelp.com/images/guides/p2042290/mts_to_xvid_vr2.zip) available. Just unzip it, put your MTS files in the folder and run the BAT file. No other user interaction needed. After some time you will have MPEG-4 AVI files, which are much smaller and more suitable to send.

There is also large discussion thread on [Videohelp.com](http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/285841-How-to-covert-from-mts-to-avi-or-wma/page4). No need to buy a converter.

Answer (score 0):

You could do much worse than trying the free and open source [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) (it just converted the MTS video coming out from my Panasonic GH2), as suggested in this thread too: [Free software for viewing/converting AVCHD](https://superuser.com/questions/40193/free-software-for-viewing-converting-avchd)