# Free software for viewing/converting AVCHD

Tags: conversion, avchd

I have a Canon HD camcorder that records in the AVCHD format, and I'm looking for some free software that can convert it to other formats. Right now, the only program I know of that can do any kind of conversion with it is Avidemux, but it doesn't do it very well. VLC is supposed to be able to play it, but the playback is too choppy to be useful.

I have Windows, although Linux software would be okay.

EDIT: I probably should also mention that it's full HD, 1080p, 60i frame rate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/)** will convert AVCHD Lite (720p) format to AVI, MP4, MKV and OGM

as for playback, use **[ffdshow](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ffdshow-tryout/)** or even better, **[CoreAVC](http://www.coreavc.com/)** (not free though).

*the nororious AVS Video Converter also claims to to be able to convert AVCHD into a number of different formats. (mov/mpg/avi/mp4/flv/3gp/rm), but i will not provide a link and you gotta be out of your mind if you even think of installing anything AVS! :)*

Comment: HandBrake also works for converting full hd AVCHD, apparently. :) And I just remembered that I got Media Player Classic to play the files with ffdshow a while ago.