# converting AVCHD to .mpg or other video format

Tags: macos, video, avchd, mts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free software for viewing/converting AVCHD](https://superuser.com/questions/40193/free-software-for-viewing-converting-avchd)

I have a Panasonic G2 camera that I took some video on, in AVCHD format. I've never used this before and I want to be able to share it with others. I finally figured out that the .MTS files are the bulk of the video content, and I was able to watch it on my Mac with [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/). But these files are part of [a whole convoluted directory structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVCHD#Overview). And I took the video in portrait mode so it's rotated 90 degrees from what it should be.

What I am looking for:

- is there a decent free converter out there besides HandBrake (for OSX) from .MTS to another format??
- are any of the other files in the convoluted directory structure important, or can I just forget about them?
- which is the best video format to convert to?
- how can I rotate 90 degrees?

Comment: Please reopen. The only one of these that is a duplicate is the question of the free converter. The other 3 parts are not duplicates.

Comment: ...and for what it's worth, the question you cited only has one answer with one software package mentioned. I am editing to ask for alternatives to HandBrake.

Comment: @Jason. Please review the FAQ. Ask one question with one answer, not 4 questions and multiple possible answers. I repeat, **one requirement** difference does not make it any less a duplicate, and asking 4 questions in one defeats the purpose of Super User. Also, no where in here do you mention handbrake? If the other question is not new enough, put a bounty on it.

Comment: @Diago: please read more carefully, I just edited immediately after my comment.

Comment: ...and apparently you guys are more strict here than StackOverflow. On SO this would not have been considered an exact duplicate. But fair enough, I'll split into separate questions.

Comment: @Jason I somehow doubt this would have been accepted on SO. But you are correct, due to the audience and content Super User is fairly strict.